# Rails helper for Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

I have a bit of HAML code that gets repeated in something like 10 views and would like to put it into a helper of some kind. Doing a search here produced some interesting results but ultimately no answers, so:

In `application_helper.rb` I have this:

```
def pagination_helper(object)
  haml_tag :div, :class => 'apple_pagination page_info' do
    page_entries_info @book_formats
    paginate @book_formats
  end
end
```

In the view template I have this:

```
- pagination_helper(@book_formats)
```

If I try calling it with `=` to output something I get an error.

The above will not give me an error but it won't call the methods either. I get empty divs.

Ultimately the code I want to repeat is this:

```
.apple_pagination.page_info
  = page_entries_info @book_formats
  = paginate @book_formats
```

The code would be the same except the `object` would change and I send that from the view template. For example `@book_formats` would change to `@dvds`, etc.

Comment: I prefer a partial over helper in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The block passed to `haml_tag` doesn’t automatically get added to the output. You need to use [`haml_concat`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_concat-instance_method):

```ruby
def pagination_helper(object)
    haml_tag :div, :class => 'apple_pagination page_info' do
        haml_concat(page_entries_info @book_formats)
        haml_concat(paginate @book_formats)
    end
end
```

Comment: What if I have this bit of code: `- if (params[:term] == 'beginning_parens' || params[:term] == 'year_at_end' || params[:term] == 'search_all_caps') %td= check_box_tag("dogTag_#{dvd.dogTag}", "#{dvd.dogTag}", 'active')`. `haml_concat` gives me an error. Is there documentation or a tutorial you could point me to for this? (thanks).

Comment: @kakubei you can’t use `=` with `haml_tag`, you need to use `-`. Instead of using `%td=...` all on one line, you’ll need to have `%td` on one line, then on the next, indented, line, use `-check_box_tag(...)`. In this case it might be easier to create a simply Ruby method that just returns a string, rather than use `haml_tag`, then you can just use `=`.